# Retrofit callback use to do something else depending on parameter

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I begin with android dev and retrofit.
My app uses datas from a mysql/apache server. All work fine with retrofit.
But, I would like to add a dummy function in the app, with a accountId == 0 (so no login), which uses datas hard coded in the app, and not on the server.

So, I'd like to modify the call, to use MY class/method if accountID == 0 AND returning the same type of result in the same callbaks as retrofit.

I try to show you with code :

MyService.java

```
interface MyService {
    @GET("get.php")
    Call<List<MyObject>> getAll(@Query("a") int accountid);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Consts.URL_SERVER)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

MyCalls.java

```
public class MyCalls {
    public interface CallbacksAll {
        void onResponse(@Nullable List<MyObject> myobjetcs);
        void onFailure();
    }

    public static void getAll(CallbacksAll callbacks, int accountId) {
        final WeakReference<CallbacksAll> callbacksWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(callbacks);
        ///////////////////
        // actually :
        ///////////////////
        MyService myService = MyService.retrofit.create(MyService.class);
        Call<List<MyObject>> call = myService.getAllByAccount(accountId);
        ///////////////////
        // end actually
        ///////////////////

        ///////////////////
        // what I'ld like
        ///////////////////
        MyService myService;
        Call<List<MyObject>> call;
        if ( accountId > 0 ) {
            myService = MyService.retrofit.create(MyService.class);
            call = myService.getAll(accountId);
        } else {
            myService = ??? // I don't really know what to create and do here
            call = MyClass.getAll(); // my class/method nevermind
        }
        ///////////////////
        // end what I'd like
        ///////////////////

        ///////////////////
        // what I'd like to NOT change
        ///////////////////
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MyObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<MyObject>> call, @NonNull Response<List<MyObject>> response) {
                if (callbacksWeakReference.get() != null)
                    callbacksWeakReference.get().onResponse(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<MyObject>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                if (callbacksWeakReference.get() != null) callbacksWeakReference.get().onFailure();
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope you will understand my poor english and what I want, and you will be able to give me ideas with simple examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, so I put my solution here.

So much time spent although the solution was so simple.
I just had to add :

```
    if (accountId == 0) {
        callbacks.onResponse(MyObject.getAll());
    } else {
        final WeakReference<CallbacksAll> callbacksWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(callbacks);
        [...]
        });
    }
```

in

```
public static void getAll(CallbacksAll callbacks, int accountId) {
```